# Will Meta.Stackoverflow.com stay as the place for general questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, meta

With the opening of [Meta.Serverfault](http://meta.serverfault.com/) will Meta.Stackoverflow still be the place to ask questions that apply to all the sites, like platform questions, formatting, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Jeff said so in a chat, unfortunately, I don't have a reference for you ([yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57394/ability-to-create-group-of-lines-of-chat))