# Where do I post a question about Microsoft Live Meeting crashing? And should I even post it?

Tags: support, questions, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, scope

My question initially was going to be where to post a general question about stack exchange (namely, where to post a question on a particular topic). Then I found [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58112/will-meta-stackoverflow-com-stay-as-the-place-for-general-questions) (and subsequently just found the same thing addressed [in the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)), so I decided to post here.

SuperUser seems to be the closest website but I wasnt sure if my topic was ok. It has to do with software (Microsoft Live Meeting crashing when sharing out a Windows 7 VM) but I wanted to make sure since I didnt find any others like that in a quick search of the site and questions about "software" (via the [site FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)) seems really broad. Also, more candidly I'm afraid of being rebuked/policed by somebody who wants to up their repuation/points/score/counts in this game, so I figured maybe I should ask if this place is appropriate to ask my question before I ask my question. Unfortunately you need 5 reputation to post on that meta, but none on this one and that's why I'm posting here (I'm sure somebody can link me to a post as to why that is as well).

The second part to my question is whether I should even post my "question" to begin with. SO has been an invaluable resource to me so I like to add to the vast repository of information on SE. Recently I was having a problem (with Live Meeting crashing) for which I couldnt find a solution online. I found the solution myself (or rather I found the root cause and remedied it). I would like to tell the world (internet) my problem and how I fixed it. So I dont have a question, I have a solution. I could put it on a blog, but I dont blog. I could put it in the form of a question, and then answer my own question (which is what I plan to do) but I feel there should be some place where I can just post solution to problems that you find on your own. Stack *Exchange* doesnt appear to be it, but maybe somebody can offer an alternative?

Comment: Why wouldn't you contact Microsoft?

Comment: @Dave ah ahah ahahahahahah aha

Comment: You, sir, are a fool and a charlatan!  Take yourself away, immediately!  ... Now that I've rebuked and policed you, how long do I have to wait until my reputation/points/score/counts increase in the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the question on SuperUser, then answer it yourself.  This is all fine and good.

The only problem you might get with your question is that it could be seen as "too localized".  Program crashes are caused by problems with an individual's setup about as much as known issues.  I'm guessing.  Maybe.

If someone (or many someones) close your question as too localized, your ego should be able to handle it.  If not, please exit the Internet at the nearest point of egress.