# Why doesn't Area 51 have its own Meta?

Tags: support, area-51, per-site-meta

[According to the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/), per-site Metas have opened up for all sites except for the special case of SO/MSO.  (Discussion about the special case is discussed further [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58159/shouldnt-you-take-the-plunge-and-have-a-per-site-meta-for-stack-overflow-too-in).)  Area 51 is not mentioned, though.  I understand that it's not exactly an SE site, but doesn't it deserve a place for meta-discussion?

Three options come immediately to mind:

- This is by design.  No meta for A51.
- `meta.area51` is coming in 6-8 weeks, just hold your unicorns.
- MSO is supposed to be the Meta for both A51 and SO, in addition to being the "national capital"  (I'd be okay with this; I just want clarification on whether it is in fact the case.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Area 51 also now has its own [Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) for meta-esque questions about site proposals. <s>Questions about Area 51 itself still belong here on MSO.</s>

**EDIT :**
[According to Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110477/what-is-the-division-of-labor-between-mso-and-the-area51-meta-tag-on-area-51/110547#110547), the Area 51 Discussion Zone is intended to serve as A51's per-site meta, and the MSO FAQ is in error.

Answer (score 5):

Area 51 is an across-all-engine site in my estimation and belongs here.

Comment: so the better question would be, why doesn't SO have it's own meta. Uhm, at meta.SO :p

Comment: I think Area 51 needs its own meta. While its topic spans all sites, its functionality is substantially different from all other sites.

Comment: @jonb the more effective argument is that Area 51 should capture its own discussion on the Area 51 site itself.

Comment: It does have its own meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/area51

Comment: I think it needs some place (not necessarily a meta discussion) for proposal authors to publicly interact.

Comment: @JeffAtwood - [Robert estimates differently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110477/what-is-the-division-of-labor-between-mso-and-the-area51-meta-tag-on-area-51/110547#110547).

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I have launched a proposal on Area51, I was super enthusiatic but I am now realizing that Area51 is surprisingly terrible at "educating" new users. I end up having to contact people directly to explain them the Area51 proposal phases, or write [such "fake" discussion to educate them](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13069/if-you-are-new-on-magnolia-cms-proposal-read-this). I suspect these obvious weaknesses could be coming from the lack of a dedicated meta for Area51.

Comment: @AdrienBe good news, there will be a real meta.stackexchange.com soon http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange and Area 51 stuff won't get lost as much there once the SO specific content is filtered out to the SO-specific meta

Comment: @JeffAtwood anything dynamic planned such as what you do on SE approved websites to "guide" new users on Area 51? A small notification for newbies who just started to "follow" a proposal for instance. Maybe something like this http://i.imgur.com/xDZmc5X.png or this http://i.imgur.com/lVvpvpB.png