# Add 'Visit Meta' link to top on SO

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, meta

For consistency, there should be a 'Visit meta' link at the top left on SO.  Every other sites' meta link is up there, SO shouldn't be left out!

Comment: All the other sites have it b/c they're *in beta*.  SO is definitely **not** in beta.

Comment: A community needs a meta site to strive, not just in beta.

Comment: @C.Ross Server Fault and Super User aren't in Beta, either.

Comment: Disregard my flag, sorry.

Comment: For even more consistency, SO should have it's own meta, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58159/shouldnt-you-take-the-plunge-and-have-a-per-site-meta-for-stack-overflow-too-in).

Comment: Looks like this is a non-issue now. A link to stackexchange.com has been added to/replaced whatever was in the upper-left.

Comment: @Bill - there's still no link to SO's meta so this is still an issue.

Comment: @Mark Actually, as I pointed out in my answer below, the "feedback always welcome" in the footer of every page takes you to the relevant meta for the site you're on. My statement of non-issue is still correct since all sites are now consistent with what is shown in the upper-left.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of one reason not to, in [this post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) Jeff explains that `meta.stackoverflow.com` is an exception to other meta sites and so it will have its own reputation system.  I.e. it doesn't really hold a parent/child relationship like the other sites.

Who is the parent to `meta.stackoverflow.com`?  More than just `stackoverflow.com` QA site is discussed here, including the `chat` feature in general, `area51`, `stackexchange`, the company itself and much else.

That being said I'm not against having a link.

Comment: That's a terrific argument for having no "parent" link back to stackoverflow.com, but a terrible argument to having no "meta" link from stackoverflow.com to meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

A meta site has been created for SU and SF, which so far have been discussed in meta. I think it would be only consequent to use meta.stackoverflow.com for SO. But I agree that then meta would have to be moved, because there has to be a place to discuss both the SE software as a whole as the special sites like Area51 and Careers.

I would argue whether StackApps could be treated like any other SE site with its own meta. There eventually will be tons of apps being discussed, such that it would allow for its own venue.

Now, the natural place to move meta to would be meta.stackexchange.com. But this is taken by all existing old SE sites as their meta. And them having their own implementation/branch of SE it would not be easy to change that, I guess.

As I like things in order, I would make these sites:

- meta.stackoverflow.com for SO
- meta.stackapps.com
- www.metaoverflow.com to discuss SE software incl. chat, area51, careers

or wait until meta.stackexchange.com is cleared and reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

The "feedback always welcome" link in the footer of SO pages links to meta. There are also several other sites where the same is observed: Stack Apps, Area 51, and Careers. Since Meta SO is used to discuss so many different sites, not placing the link in the upper-left may be a tactic to help keep noise down.