# Should there be a separate site for questions about the "Stack Exchange engine"?

Tags: feature-request, meta

*[I have to assume this has been discussed before, but my searches didn't turn anything up. Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.]*

It feels incongruous to me that this site (meta.stackoverflow.com) has such a different mission than all the other meta sites.

**From the Stack Overflow meta faq:**

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - Stack Overflow
> - Stack Exchange Area 51
> - The core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites
>
> ...it is welcome here.

**From the Super User (and I assume all other sites) meta faq:**

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> This site is for meta discussion about superuser.com. That is, things like:
>
> 1. Are questions about {subject} on or off topic?
> 2. What should our FAQ contain?
> 3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?
> 4. What should our elevator pitch be?
> 5. What should our logo and site design look like?
> 6. Who should the moderators be?
> 7. How do we promote our site?

Also, meta.stackoverflow.com continues to have its own separate reputation, while all the other meta sites just use the reputation of the main site (and you don't earn reputation for meta questions and answers).

So, I'm wondering if it would make sense to create something like meta.stackengine.com (I would say it should be meta.stackexchange.com, but that seems to have a different purpose) for questions about the Stack Exchange engine. What does everyone think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shouldn't you take the plunge and have a per-site Meta for Stack Overflow too in favor of meta.stackexchange.com?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58159/shouldnt-you-take-the-plunge-and-have-a-per-site-meta-for-stack-overflow-too-in)

Comment: yeah, it's historical. Back in the day, when MSO launched, SO was pretty much the only site in the "network." SF had only been around for a month, and SU and the rest didn't exist yet. So, questions about the engine and questions about SO tended to be the same thing. Then SE 1.0 happened, and meta for that had to be separate. And now we have all these SE 2.0 sites, but everything's already been on MSO for so long that it'd be confusing and painful to change it, and of course that only gets more true with each passing day....

Comment: (@Dan the above comment is more for people who wander by later than for you personally)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a little incongruous but the question load on meta is already pretty low so it seems like creating another site would just divide people's attention even further without much benefit.

How would it be different from meta.stackexchange.com anyway, you never really explained that?

Comment: Maybe meta.stackexchange.com would work...but it looks like the main site (stackexchange.com) is currently intended to highlight the best of all the stackexchange sites.