# Typo/mis-information in /privileges/participate-in-meta on SO

Tags: bug, status-completed

On SO, when going to the overview of [reputation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges), following the link to [participate in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta) it says:

> **Why do I need 5 rep to post there?**
>
> Your reputation on meta is the same as
>   your reputation on the parent site.
>
> You can always read meta with no rep
>   at all.
>
> Because we allow anonymous
>   participation, we require a small bit
>   of parent site reputation to prevent
>   spam, and ensure that meta is for
>   active, engaged members of the
>   community.

But if I've understood it correctly, this isn't correct - at least not the part about "is the same as your reputation on the parent site". You can link link your accounts, but they still have separate reputation scores, right?

Comment: [Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow are the exception to the rule.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58159/shouldnt-you-take-the-plunge-and-have-a-per-site-meta-for-stack-overflow-too-in) You're right though, this should be changed. +1

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have been fixed:

> **Why do I need 5 rep to post there?**
>
> The following applies to all per-site Metas except Stack Overflow. You do not need Stack Overflow rep to post on its Meta, *and your rep on its Meta isn't tied to the parent site.*
>
> **Otherwise:**
>
> Your reputation on meta is the same as your reputation on the parent site.
>
> You can always read meta with no rep at all.
>
> Because we allow anonymous participation, we require a small bit of parent site reputation to prevent spam, and ensure that meta is for active, engaged members of the community.

(Italic emphasis mine)