# Removing merging meta.se

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shouldn't you take the plunge and have a per-site Meta for Stack Overflow too in favor of meta.stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58159/shouldnt-you-take-the-plunge-and-have-a-per-site-meta-for-stack-overflow-too-in)

Today I was just on http://meta.stackexchange.com and I was shocked to find out that there is still a message for Area 51's public beta and most of the questions are on there at least 1 year old. I was wondering if there is a plan to merge all the questions and tags to here and the rep to.