# Why is this meta different from the others?

Tags: discussion, meta

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Will the StackExchange meta site behaviour be backported to the trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56556/will-the-stackexchange-meta-site-behaviour-be-backported-to-the-trilogy)
>   [Will Meta.Stackoverflow.com stay as the place for general questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58112/will-meta-stackoverflow-com-stay-as-the-place-for-general-questions)

It seemed like at first the meta-stackoverflow was the meta for all the mains sites, SF, SU, SO. But now they each have their own. If you visit SF or SU there is a link on the top directly to the respective meta (this is absent on SO though). Also when you view the other metas the REP is shared across the main site and the respective meta (this is not the case with SO meta).

I was just wondering if there was a reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: They've grown to be intrinsically different communities, and need their own place to discuss things. If the parent site trusts you, why should the meta site be any different?

Comment: MSO is the "national capital meta" according to Jeff; I'm not 100% on board with the analogy, but the point is that it doesn't serve only SO in the way that other metas serve only their parent site.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56556/will-the-stackexchange-meta-site-behaviour-be-backported-to-the-trilogy

Comment: See: [Will Meta.Stackoverflow.com stay as the place for general questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58112/will-meta-stackoverflow-com-stay-as-the-place-for-general-questions)

Comment: @Tim I wasn't asking why they were a certain way, I was asking why "this" one is different than the others. I also wasn't suggesting anything was wrong with either way, I was just wondering what the reason behind it was.

Comment: I understand why it got closd, but whats the down-vote for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [recent blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/):

> For now we are leaving meta.stackoverflow.com grandfathered in, as-is, with no changes; it’s still a standalone community with a standalone reputation system. We think Stack Overflow is large enough to justify this, and it just so happens that Stack Overflow is also the name of the company, too. Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals.

<sub>I copied this word for word from a user who chose to delete their answer. If that user would like to come forward, I'll gladly attach your name to it.</sub>